# Android Studio Arctic Fox: Problem Loading Widget

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a very simple widget that would show me an activity on click. However, once deployed, it shows me only "Problem Loading Widget". I've tried everything I found on the net: I checked the @Override's, I changed the widget button layout to Relative from Constraint, but nothing worked, it's still just "Problem Loading Widget". Logcat doesn't show anything. Please help.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr_code_banner"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.mine.qrcode_widget;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.widget_layout);
        }
    }
```

QR_code_widget.java:

```
    package com.mine.qrcode_widget;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.widget.RemoteViews;
    
    public class QR_code_widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            for (int appWidget : appWidgetIds) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    
                @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout") RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);
    
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
            }
        }
    }
```

extender_appwidget_info.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
        android:previewLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
        android:minHeight="110dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:resizeMode="none"
        android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
        android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
        android:previewImage="@drawable/qr_code_banner">
    </appwidget-provider>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mine.qrcode_widget">
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/qr_code_logo"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Covid19qrcodewidget">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".QR_code_widget" android:label="Covid-19 QR-Code Card">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/extender_appwidget_info"/>
            </receiver>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Use `android:src`, not `app:srcCompat`, when creating a layout for an app widget. Basically, stuff from `app` may not work. Also, you do not have any layout rules in your `RelativeLayout` to indicate where the `ImageButton` should appear -- in this case, it does not appear that you necessarily need the `RelativeLayout`.